Using @prisma/extension-read-replica is there a way to redirect queries to writer instance if reader fails? this doesn't seems to default behaviour
I have an aws aurora postgres RDS having reader and writer instance, I connected it with my next.js application using prisma, and I setup the reader replica as mentioned in this doc, but this doc seems to be so limited with not much details. So I wanted to know if somehow my read replica goes down, will the read write both traffic be served by my writer instance? If not is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

I'm using the NextAuth with Auth0 for authentication and these libs are querying the db on firstload in order to check if user existing in the db and get information about user. so what I did is i just altered my reader instance hostname in order to check if the prisma.user.findUnique() query get redirected to the writer, but it thrown error saying can't connect to the database

I tried failing over the reader instance the same behaviour as above was found


If the way I tested, if that was wrong I appreciate any suggestions.
So can anyone suggest a way to achieve the below behaviour?
if reader fails to connect, the queries should get redirected to writer
